# Using an enum having entries with the same value of underlying type

Tags: c#, .net, enums

if i declare an enum like

```
enum Weekdays
{
    Mon = 1,
    Tue = 1,
    Wen = 1,
    Thi,
    Fri,
    Sat,
    Sun
}

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);//Prints Tue why?
```

now if i change Weekdays and do the same operation  as follows

```
enum Weekdays
{
    Mon = 1,
    Tue = 1,
    Wen = 1,
    Thi = 1,
    Fri,
    Sat,
    Sun
}

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);//Prints Thi !!!!!How?
```

What is really happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Per MSDN [If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It happens that if you have 3 or 4 days linked to the same number:1, you get a random day among the 3 or the 4 and it is unpredictable. Why do you want 3 or 4 days with the same number?

Comment: i was just checking what happens when they got same value ,You are right we Can't predict the output as by MSDN [If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  any way thanks dude

Answer (score 8):

When you write out your value like this, it ends up getting `ToString()` called on it.

```
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

If you dig into the code far enough down, it's calling `Enum.GetName()` on your value.

Regarding multiple enum values with the same underlying value, the `Enum.GetName` page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value, the GetName method guarantees that it will return the name of one of those enumeration members. However, it does not guarantee that it will always return the name of the same enumeration member. As a result, when multiple enumeration members have the same value, your application code should never depend on the method returning a particular member's name.

It doesn't state *how* it determines which name to return if the values on two or more are the same.

The docs for [`Enum.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw(v=vs.100).aspx) include the same warning, in slightly different wording.

Digging a little deeper, the method above makes a call to `Array.BinarySearch`, passing it an array of numbers representing all values in your enum, and a number representing the value you want to print.

So you have an array with multiple `1`'s in it, and you're searching for a `1`. The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx) for that call are similar:

> Duplicate elements are allowed. If the Array contains more than one element equal to value, the method returns the index of only one of the occurrences, and not necessarily the first one.

Again, it doesn't state *how* a selection is made, just that it'll be unreliable.

Comment: Hey can you please read my answer and tell me if it makes sense?

Comment: @grant winney :: actually what works here ToString() or Enum.GetName() ?

Comment: I believe the reason you get the response is because of the hash codes of the various values: Mon=77548, Tue=84452, Wen=86848, Thi=84053. If you just have Mon, Tue, and Wen = 1, then the binary search lands on Tue (it's in the middle), but if you add Thi = 1 so you have 4 items, then the binary search will land on the second element, which would be Thi.

Answer (score 4):

When you assign similar values, the result will be unexpected but I think it will evaluate for two cases:

**When n is even:**

```
(n/2)
```

**When n is odd:**

```
(n/2)+1
```

If I change the `enum` like this:

```
enum Weekdays {Mon=1,Tue=1,Wen=1,Thi=1,Fri=1,Sat=1, Sun=1, Mon2=1, Mon3=1}
// n is odd = 9
// (n/2)+1 = 5

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

The result will be `Fri`, Now lets change the `enum` again:

```
enum Weekdays {Mon=1,Tue=1,Wen=1,Thi=1,Fri=1,Sat=1, Sun=1,Mon2=1}
// n is even = 8
// (n/2) = 4

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

The result is now `Thi`, Again change the `enum`:

```
enum Weekdays {Mon=1,Tue=1,Wen=1,Thi=1,Fri=1,Sat=1, Sun=1}
// n is odd = 7
// (n/2)+1 = 4

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

The result is now `Thi`, Again change the `enum`:

```
enum Weekdays {Mon=1,Tue=1,Wen=1,Thi=1,Fri=1,Sat=1}
// n is even = 6
// (n/2) = 3

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

The result is now `Wen`, Again change the `enum`:

```
enum Weekdays {Mon=1,Tue=1,Wen=1,Thi=1,Fri=1}
// n is odd = 5
// (n/2)+1 = 3

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

The result is now `Wen`, Changing the `enum` again:

```
enum Weekdays {Mon=1,Tue=1,Wen=1,Thi=1}
// n is even = 4
// (n/2) = 2

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

The result is now `Tue`, Changing the `enum` again:

```
enum Weekdays {Mon=1,Tue=1,Wen=1}
// n is odd = 3
// (n/2)+1 = 2

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

The result is now `Tue`.

Even though this is explaining the behavior perfectly but this may not always happen or may not happen since I have not checked this for more cases but as MSDN says you should not assume about such output when the `enum` have same values for different names...

That said, I think you can easily understand now what is happening in your code.

Ref.: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

## Edit:

@GrantWinney's answer led me to this, He has written that `Array.BinarySearch` is passed the array of values and the value to search for so I realized from the name `Array.BinarySearch` that it is definitely using a `BinarySearch` and that explains everything...

[Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) will divide the array like this:

```
Mid = {Low(which is the starting index) + High (which is the last index of array)}/2
```

and then Check for

```
if (Mid == value) return index;
else 
 if the value is smaller or equal move left other wise move right of the array
```

So this explains it how the `enum` values are printed if their are multiple names for the value you are trying to print.

**Your Original Question**

```
enum Weekdays
{
    Mon = 1,
    Tue = 1,
    Wen = 1,
    Thi,
    Fri,
    Sat,
    Sun
}

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);//Prints Tue why?
```

It prints `Tue` because a call to `Array.BinarySearch` will be made passing the array

```
{1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

and a value to search which is `1`...

So the `BinarySearch` will do this:

```
Mid = {Low(0) + High(6)} / 2
if (Mid == value) return index
else move left
```

After moving left again the `Mid` will be calculated:

```
High = Mid - 1; // now only the left sub-array will be searched
Mid = {Low(0) + High(2)} / 2
if (Mid == value) return index // here the condition will be true and you will be returned with `Tue`
```

**The 2nd example in your Question:**

```
enum Weekdays
{
    Mon = 1,
    Tue = 1,
    Wen = 1,
    Thi = 1,
    Fri,
    Sat,
    Sun
}

Weekdays obj = (Weekdays)1;
Console.WriteLine(obj);//Prints Thi !!!!!How?
```

As I have written above a call to `Array.BinarySearch` will be made and array:

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

will be passed with value = `1` to search...

Apply the `BinarySearch` algorithm on the array and it will evaluate to `Thi`.

Comment: :in your enum all constants have same value if my enum is like `enum WeekDays {Mon=1,Tue=1,Wen,Thi,Fri=1,sat,Sun }; WeekDays obj = (WeekDays)1;
            Console.WriteLine(obj);//prints fri` Can you tell me why?

Comment: Yes I changed it because I was trying to explain what happens when you have same values for different names in an enum.

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr I can not yet, But I have written that there is a pattern in my answer but that can not be 100% since it is written on MSDN that the output will be unexpected when the enum has same values for different names...

Comment: Don't know how constructive it is to try to reverse-engineer how .Net does this. The implementation may be different in different versions of .Net, and Microsoft may change the implementation in future versions. Then there's Mono, and (hopefully) other C# implementations coming in the future, each of which may do it differently.

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi : Now you are saying that enum definitely using a BinarySearch and that explains everything... .if so my enum is like this `enum WeekDays
        {
            Mon=1,
            Tue=1,
            Wen,
            Thi,
            Fri=1,
            sat,
            Sun
        }` now try the following code `WeekDays obj = (WeekDays)1;
            Console.WriteLine(obj);//print fri` can you explaian why? as per your explanation it must print Tue but it's not.