# Enum duplicate values gives duplicate names

Tags: c#, enums, duplicates

Before starting implemeting the logic of duplicate values for enum, i read several questions here but then i faced the following problem:

I have the following enum:

```
public enum Features
{
    X1= 3,
    X2= 3,
    X3= 6,
    X4= 6,
    X5= 6,
    X6= 6,
    X7= 10,
    X8= 10,
}
```

After that i tried creating a list like this:

```
var features = new List<Features>(){X1,X2,X3,X5,X6,X7,X8};
```

When i look at the list in debug mode, the list contains the following enums:

```
X1,X1,X3,X3,X3,X7,X7
```

Why does this happen, does it call GetName() implicitly ? 
Is there a solution to this issue ?

Comment: The question is: why do you want to do such a thing? Enums are lists of different elements/strings, which are also defined on account of a set of distinct integers (by default, their positions). Having two elements associated with the same integer would go against such an idea. If you want to associate a set of strings to a set of integers (which might be repeated or not), you should rely on a different approach; for example: a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Comment: You're basically trying to go from a many to one relationship, and trying to reverse engineer your "one" value (i.e. 6) and figure out which of the "many" it came from (i.e. X3, X4, X5, or X6). You can see why that would be an issue. It's like throwing your cell phone into a pile of seemingly-identical phones, and hoping you grab the right one back every time.

Comment: Se also [Using an enum having entries with the same value of underlying type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26321509/3538012)

Comment: I am aware of all what have been said here, but i decided to use this way instead of dictionary cause its more easy to use and more readable. I tried reading about it first and read that there is nothing in the documentation that explicitly says you can't have duplicate values. So i went with it, but found no further help after

Comment: The explanation of the behavior is clear enough. You ask for a solution "to this issue", but it's not clear what "issue" you are trying to solve. When you declare more than one enum value name as having the same underlying value, what is the debugger or other value-to-string conversion supposed to do with a value that has more than one name? What do _you_ expect it to do?

Comment: The values added to list are exactly the ones shown in debugger. When you do list.Add(X2) the item X1 will be added.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: _"When you do list.Add(X2) the item X1 will be added"_ -- while I suppose technically true, that's a very confusing way to look at it, as you are implying that the item `X2` is _not_ added. It's not that one enum name or the other is added; it's that what gets added is actually the _value_, and there's not a one-to-one mapping between names and values.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes. I agree with you. Same values yields same result ;)

Answer (score -1):

I dont´t think there is a good way to use enumerators, because enums are alias to encapsulate integer numbers.

Why use different alias to encapsulate the same number?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx